# CSS Hover Door opening effect is not working on Safari

Tags: css, onhover

On hover, the doors are supposed to be open, according to the CSS. It works in Firefox, Opera, Chrome and IE but there is no effect on hover in Safari 5.1.7. Where's the problem here? The part of the CSS for this hover is the following:

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  background: #C2B3A0;
}
/*user-select: none;*/
/*background: url(bg.jpg);*/
#cupboard {
    height: 613px;
    width: 617px;
    position: relative;
    left: 35%;
    margin-left: -112px;
    top: 24px;
    bottom: 31px;
    perspective: 500;
    background: url(bg.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 95%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#cupboard img {
    position: inherit;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 62px;
    margin-top: 82px;
}



#cupboard .door#left {
  zoom:.6;
  position: absolute;
  width: 512px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(dl.jpg);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
  transform: rotateY(0);
}
#cupboard .door#right {
  zoom:.6;
  position: absolute;
  width: 517px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(dr.jpg);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
  transform: rotateY(0);
}
#cupboard .door#left {
  transform-origin: top left;
  left: 0;
}
#cupboard .door#right {
  transform-origin: top right;
  right: 0;
}
#cupboard:hover #left,
#cupboard.hover #left {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
}
#cupboard:hover #right,
#cupboard.hover #right {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
```

Here is the Html code:-

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="cupboard">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
    <img src="f.jpeg" alt="facebook"/></a>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com">
    <img src="t.jpeg" alt="twiter"/></a>
    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com">
    <img src="l.png" alt="linkedin"/></a>
    <a href="http://www.wordpress.com">
    <img src="w.jpg" alt="wordpress"/></a>

    <div class="door" id="left"></div>

    <div class="door" id="right"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the jQuery code:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#cupboard").on("touchstart", function(e) { 
  $(this).addClass("hover");
  e.preventDefault();
});

$("body").on("touchend", function(e) {
  $("#cupboard").removeClass("hover");
});

});
```

Here is the sreenshot of output page:-

**Before hover :-**
[image]

**After hover :-**
[image]

Comment: If you need jQuery code then i'll provide it too.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes according to your given link it should work on safari 5.1.7 but it's not working and i'am using windows 7. Is there is any problem due to OS. Is I need to use mac?